PrimeNG: Drag & Drop tree node between Trees in different components
I'm working on Drag & Drop between two PrimeNG trees.
In my case, i have two primeng trees each in a separated angular component.
is that possible to keep the drag and drop working between these two trees ?
I know that having multiple trees in same component, drag and drop can work fine.
Nothing mentioned in the documentation of primeng tree component also drag & drop section.
